# Delete geographic point in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, geohashing

I am using [Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB](https://github.com/renet/dynamodb-geo-v3) to use geopoints in my project, putting my geopoints with this module already works, but now I have problems deleting the points, according to the documentation when you want to delete a point you have to do this:

```
myGeoTableManager
  .deletePoint({
    RangeKeyValue: { S: "1234" },
    GeoPoint: {
      // An object specifying latitutde and longitude as plain numbers.
      latitude: 51.51,
      longitude: -0.13,
    },
    DeleteItemInput: {
      // Optional, any additional parameters to pass through.
      // TableName and Key are filled in for you
      // Example: Only delete if the point does not have a country name set
      ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(country)",
    },
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Done!");
  });
```

According to the documentation, the name of the table and its keys are filled automatically but I get an error that precisely those fields are missing

The hash key and range key are automatic when you put a geopoint, so I really don't know what values they are and I can't access them, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The hash key and table name are added for you, if your config is correct. You can see it's implementation [here](https://github.com/renet/dynamodb-geo-v3/blob/6c54786ca35e023eeaee33500813cee6956790df/src/dynamodb/DynamoDBManager.ts#L233)

My concern is more to the fact that you're using a library which was forked from an archived library which has not been maintained on 10 years. Moreover, the package you are using hasn't been maintained in a number of years either, and still uses SDK V2. If your application is ever going to be used in production, I strongly advise seeking alternative solutions.